# How to find common rows between two dataframe in R?

Tags: r

I would like to make a new data frame which only includes common rows of two separate data.frame.
example:

data.frame 1

```
1 id300
2 id2345
3 id5456
4 id33
5 id45
6 id54
```

data.frame2

```
1 id832
2 id300
3 id1000
4 id45
5 id984
6 id5456
7 id888
```

So I want my output be:

```
1 id300
2 id45
3 id5456
```

any suggestion please?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
common <- intersect(data.frame1$col, data.frame2$col)  
data.frame1[common,] # give you common rows in data frame 1  
data.frame2[common,] # give you common rows in data frame 2
```

Comment: I also like `dplyr`s intersect (seperate package)

Comment: I think this answer is not answering the question correctly. It does not even generalize to data.frames with two or more columns.

Comment: Agree with @raymkchow. Works fine for the specific example where there's only one column per dataframe, but would be nice to have a more general solution

Comment: Beware of `intersect` !  If you happen to have a certain value show up twice in both dataframes,  you will only get one of those rows returned.  You may or may not want this effect.

Answer (score 39):

The appropriate `dplyr` function here is `inner_join` (returns all rows from df `x` that have a match in df `y`.)

```
library(dplyr)
inner_join(df1, df2)

      V1
1  id300
2 id5456
3   id45
```

Note: the rows are returned in the order in which they are in `df1`. If you did `inner_join(df2, df1)`, `id45` would come before `id5456`.

Comment: Is it possible to delete the intersection from df1?

Comment: Yes, I think you would use `anti_join(df1, df2)`. Check out the function documentation for the specifics.

Answer (score 7):

Use `merge`

```
new_data_frame <- merge(data.frame1, data.frame2)
```

I'm assuming you have only one column in each data frame and they have the same name in both frames. If not use the column you want to intersect by with `by.x = "nameCol1"` and `by.y = "nameCol2"`, where nameCol are the real column names.

**Added after first comment**
If you have more columns in any data frame the command is the same. Do it this way:

```
>a  #Data frame 1
      c1 c2
1  id300  6
2 id2345  5
3 id5456  4
4   id33  3
5   id45  2
6   id54  1

> b #Data frame 2
     a  f
1  asd 12
2 id33 10
3 id45  8
4 id54  6
```

As you may see, they don't share column names and have 2 columns each. So:

```
> merge(a,b, by.x = "c1", by.y = "a")

    c1 c2  f
1 id33  3 10
2 id45  2  8
3 id54  1  6
```

The only rows that are left are those that have the same entries in common in the selected columns.

Comment: if I have more than one column in secound data frame and if I want them to show up in new data frame then how should I change this command?

Answer (score 6):

We can also do this with `fintersect` from `data.table` after converting the `data.frame` to `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
fintersect(setDT(df1), setDT(df2))
#       v1
#1:  id300
#2:   id45
#3: id5456
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(v1 = c("id300", "id2345", "id5456", "id33", "id45", 
"id54")), .Names = "v1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))

df2 <- structure(list(v1 = c("id832", "id300", "id1000", "id45", "id984", 
"id5456", "id888")), .Names = "v1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"))
```

Comment: how to do the same with multiple columns in a single dataframe ? I have 37 columns which are unequal in length ...

Comment: @krushnachChandra  Not clear about your issue.  Do you want to get the intersect from a single data.frame.  then do `Reduce(intersect, df1)`

Answer (score 3):

To achieve this, you should assign the row names in both data frame and then process with intersect in R. This can be achieved with the following command:

```
intersect(dataframe.1$V1,dataframe.2$V2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it might simply be useful to get a logical vector indicating which rows in a dataframe or matrix `a` are identical to rows in dataframe or matrix `b`, optionally over a (sub)set of `subcol` columns:

```
duplicated(rbind(
    b[, subcol, drop = FALSE],
    a[, subcol, drop = FALSE]
))[(nrow(b) + 1): (nrow(b) + nrow(a))]
```

No add-on package required. Mind that entries in `a[, subcol, drop = FALSE]` must not be duplicated themselves.

Answer (score -1):

Use intersect function of dplyr  package

1. install this package
2. use this function like

   var_name  <- intersect(Name of 1st dataset, Name of 2nd dataset)

The best thing about this is it can work with character also while merge and inner_join cannot able to give results
also you can use this function to see where is their location on your dataset

```
for (i in (no. of duplicates ) ) {
 for (j in ( no. of rows in other dataset  ) ) {
  if (new[i] == ac$variable_name[j]) {
  print(j)
  }
  } 
}
```