# R Create table that contains common elements between two tables

Tags: r

I have a data table called DT in R and I have a subtable called VIDEOSEL. I want to create a new table called NDT that contains the rows of DT only if they appear in VIDEOSEL.

For example: DT=

```
NAME UNID
54   4
37   7
122  8
```

VIDEOSEL=

```
NAME UNID
54   14
```

NDT=

```
NAME UNID
54   4
```

I have this code

```
NDT<-NULL
 for (i in 1:dim(DT)[1]){
   mat<-is.na(match(DT$NAME[i],VIDEOSEL$NAME))
   if(mat)
     {
       NDT<-rbind(NDT,DT[i,])
  }
}
```

The problem is that it is terribly slow because DT has 150000 elements. How can I improve the peformance?

Thanks a lot

Comment: lookup `merge`. many answers to similar questions here

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32917934/how-to-find-common-rows-between-two-dataframe-in-r/32918022#32918022

Comment: If you are open to installing a package, you can take the `intersect` of two data.frames after loading a package called dplyr.