# finding common strings across two data frame

Tags: r, data.table

I have read this [How to find common rows between two dataframe in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32917934/how-to-find-common-rows-between-two-dataframe-in-r)

I have two data

```
df1 <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 3L, 2L, 4L), .Label = c("AMH5", 
"BBHD", "DHE3", "NF1"), class = "factor")), .Names = "V1", class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x103007b78>)
```

and

```
df2<- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(4L, 2L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("AMH5 ", 
"BBDQ ", "DHE3", "TBB5 "), class = "factor")), .Names = "V1", class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x103007b78>)
```

unfortunatelly I cannot find where the problem is when I have several similar strings while not all detected. For example when I do this

```
library(data.table)
fintersect(setDT(df1), setDT(df2))
```

It shows only one

```
V1
1: DHE3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your data, little bit of cleaning is required.

```
# convert to character (if needed)
df1 <- df1[, lapply(.SD, as.character)]
df2 <- df2[, lapply(.SD, as.character)]

# trim whitespace
library(stringr)
df1 <- df1[, lapply(.SD, str_trim)]
df2 <- df2[, lapply(.SD, str_trim)]

# get output
fintersect(df1, df2)

     V1
1: DHE3
2: AMH5
```

Comment: I get some error `df1 <- df1[, lapply(.SD, as.character)]
Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list' `

Comment: That's weird. I just ran it. Could you reload your df1 and df2 and try again.

Comment: do you know what was the problem? I should have converted them into data.table first before I convert to character . So it solved the issue and I accepted your answer . thanks

Comment: convert to data.table ? But, the format you gave in question is already in data.table format. Strange! Anyways, glad your problem is solved.