# Intersection using two columns in data-frame

Tags: r

I want to intersect my data-frame based on two columns single column i can do that using the intersect function but how to go about two columns.

Here is my sample data-frame

```
head(Region)
          ENSEMBL UP_DOWN
1 ENSG00000000457      UP
2 ENSG00000000460      UP
3 ENSG00000000938      UP
4 ENSG00000000971      UP
5 ENSG00000001084    DOWN
6 ENSG00000001460      UP
```

The second data-frame

```
head(gene)
          ENSEMBL UP_DOWN
1 ENSG00000000003    DOWN
2 ENSG00000000938      UP
3 ENSG00000001630    DOWN
4 ENSG00000002822    DOWN
5 ENSG00000004059    DOWN
6 ENSG00000004139    DOWN
```

So far what im doing is this

```
c <- as.data.frame(intersect(Region$ENSEMBL,gene$ENSEMBL))
```

But I lose the information if that respective row is either "`UP`" or "`DOWNN`" in either of my data-frame. How do i label that? information

Comment: The options in this link should work as well - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32917934/how-to-find-common-rows-between-two-dataframe-in-r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do an inner join:

```
library(dplyr)

inner_join(Region, gene, by = c('ENSEMBL','UP_DOWN'))

          ENSEMBL UP_DOWN
1 ENSG00000000938      UP
```

Comment: but would it tell me if the "UP" in both cases like both my dataframe is "UP" ?

Comment: checked  few of them so it matches but now if one row is UP in one data-frame and "DOWN" in the other then it wont come in the output..

Comment: You could just join by 'ENSEMBL' only : you'll see both sides. I joined by `c('ENSEMBL','UP_DOWN')` because you asked for an intersect

Comment: We can use suffix argument to name the repeated columns:  inner_join(Region, gene, by = c('ENSEMBL'), suffix = c('_Region', '_Gene'))

Answer (score 2):

A base R option with `merge` may help

```
> merge(Region, gene)
          ENSEMBL UP_DOWN
1 ENSG00000000938      UP
```